# Xamarin Form and Bluetooth disconnect

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there an event of a `Android.Bluetooth` class that is raised when the device is disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set add a `BluetoothGattCallback`

```
public class MyGattCallback : BluetoothGattCallback
{
    public override void OnConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, GattStatus status, ProfileState newState)
    {
        base.OnConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        if(newState == ProfileState.Disconnected)
        {
            // disconnected
        }
    }
}
```

And when you connect your device, you pass it:

```
BluetoothDevice device = ...;
var callback = new MyGattCallback();
device.ConnectGatt(Application.Context, false, callback);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The code var callback = new BluetoothGattCallback(); it's correct? Or you mean  var callback = new MyGattCallback ();? Thanks

Comment: Gatt is something LE related.